# Changing logging levels localized name with jdk logging/slf4j

Tags: java, logging, localization, slf4j

I see that logging levels using jdk logging are localized, running this example:

```
package com.stackoverflow.tests.logging;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class TestLogging
{

    public static void doLog(Locale l)
    {
        Locale.setDefault(l);

        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestLogging.class.getName());

        final String msg = "Hello logging world";
        logger.severe(msg);
        logger.info(msg);
        logger.config(msg);
        logger.fine(msg);
        logger.finer(msg);
        logger.finest(msg);

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        doLog(Locale.ITALY);

    //  doLog(Locale.UK);

    //  doLog(Locale.FRANCE);

    }
}
```

Ouput for italian (using default logger configuration hence only severe and info levels are logged)

```
dic 15, 2014 10:48:43 AM com.stackoverflow.tests.logging.TestLogging doLog
Grave: Hello logging world
dic 15, 2014 10:48:43 AM com.stackoverflow.tests.logging.TestLogging doLog
Informazioni: Hello logging world
```

I would like to set up custom localized message for logging levels instead of the one provided by default.

How can I do that

1. Using JDK logging directly (I see `Logger.getLogger` can take a ResourceBundle but I did not manage to make it work, and also I dont know what is expected to be in this file)
2. Using SLF4 facade (I guess that would imply tweaking `LoggerFactory.getLogger` function of SLF4J which is the one I'm using to obtain the loggers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on some testing, it doesn't seem possible to do this with JDK logging.

The resource bundle name passed to `Logger` doesn't influence the `Level` object that creates the localized name. Instead, it uses a default resource bundle (`sun.util.logging.resources.logging`) to obtain a text version of the level.

My test comprised of a file named `logmessages.properties` containing:

```
INFO="NEWINFO"
testmessage="fooballs"
```

and a simple class:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LocaleLoggingTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("name", "logmessages");
    logger.info("testmessage");
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Dec 15, 2014 10:23:39 AM LocaleLoggingTest main
INFO: "fooballs"
```

If you debug, by the time  you get to `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format(LogRecord)`, the log record has a `Level` object with a default resource bundle. Frustrating, eh?

Answer (score 0):

In `java.util.logging`, you can define your own levels using a different bundle name or none at all. The way to do that is subclassing `java.util.logging.Level` and adding your own constants. For example, if you want non-localized names, you can create your levels as follows:

```
public class Level extends java.util.logging.Level {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1283674772992561191L;

    public static final Level OFF = new Level("OFF", Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    public static final Level SEVERE = new Level("SEVERE", 1000);
    public static final Level WARNING = new Level("WARNING", 900);
    public static final Level INFO = new Level("INFO", 800);
    public static final Level CONFIG = new Level("CONFIG", 700);
    public static final Level FINE = new Level("FINE", 500);
    public static final Level FINER = new Level("FINER", 400);
    public static final Level FINEST = new Level("FINEST", 300);
    public static final Level ALL = new Level("ALL", Integer.MIN_VALUE);

    protected Level(String name, int value) {
        super(name, value);
    }
}
```

If you want to use another bundle name, do the following:

```
public class Level extends java.util.logging.Level {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1283674772992561191L;

    static final String my_bundle_name = "my.bundle.name";

    public static final Level OFF = new Level("OFF", Integer.MAX_VALUE, my_bundle_name);
    public static final Level SEVERE = new Level("SEVERE", 1000, my_bundle_name);
    public static final Level WARNING = new Level("WARNING", 900, my_bundle_name);
    public static final Level INFO = new Level("INFO", 800, my_bundle_name);
    public static final Level CONFIG = new Level("CONFIG", 700, my_bundle_name);
    public static final Level FINE = new Level("FINE", 500, my_bundle_name);
    public static final Level FINER = new Level("FINER", 400, my_bundle_name);
    public static final Level FINEST = new Level("FINEST", 300, my_bundle_name);
    public static final Level ALL = new Level("ALL", Integer.MIN_VALUE, my_bundle_name);

    protected Level(String name, int value, String resourceBundleName) {
        super(name, value, resourceBundleName);
    }
}
```

Of course, you must use your custom levels instead of the default ones, so you must use calls like `Logger.log(Level level, String msg)`, where you specify the level explicitly, instead of `Logger.info(String msg)`, that always uses the default level.

EDIT: I got the idea from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html#Level-java.lang.String-int-